# Erro no build do Maven - Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: java, maven

Aparece essa mensagem na minha aplicação Maven

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer um build Maven com o comando clean package

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PedidoVenda 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/outjected/simple-email/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/outjected/simple-email/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/simple-email-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.outjected:simple-email:jar:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/outjected/simple-email/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/simple-email-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.442 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-27T18:34:09-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PedidoVenda: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.algaworks:PedidoVenda:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.outjected:simple-email:jar:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT in prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

O que será que está acontecendo?

E como resolver o problema?

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.algaworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>PedidoVenda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Implementacao do Bean Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Driver JDBC do MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Weld (implementação do CDI) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PrimeFaces (biblioteca de componentes) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mojarra (implementacao do JSF) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.21</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OmniFaces (utilitarios para JSF) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4J -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Logging (abstrai a implementação de logging) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Lang (utilidades) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Abstração para envio de e-mails -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.outjected</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-email</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Requerido para envio de e-mails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Usamos para templates de emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Usamos para formatar números em templates -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools-generic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security (autenticação e autorização) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API de Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>PedidoVenda</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o seu pom.xml completo?
Ajudaria também se você postar seu settings.xml
Ele fica nesse diretório: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: A propósito, qual é a versão do Maven que você está usando?

Answer (score 0):

Logo abaixo do comentário

```
<!-- Abstração para envio de e-mails -->
```

Está sendo definido como dependencia o seguinte jar: `simple-email:jar`

No seu pom.xml você também define um repository, onde o Maven faz o lookup das dependências:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

O Maven não está achando essa dependencia nesse repositório. Em qual ele está ai já não posso te ajudar, ẽ possçivel que esteja seja um problema de acesso a este repositório. Mas quando passei por problemas semelhantes, tomei o seguinte *approach*

Primeiro, rode:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Na sequencia, faça os seguintes checks:

- Check se o repositório que você acessa pede antenticacão. o maven não consegue forncecer as credenciais corretas. Elas são colocadas no seu arquivo ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
- O repositório que você está tentando acessar usa SSL, e a JVM executando o Maven, não confia nestes certificados.
- Existem problemas na sua rede, por exemplo, está faltando algum proxy para acessar este repositório
- O Maven não consegue salvar os arquivos no seu resitório local, por exemplo, o Maven não tem permissão para salvar.

Por último, mas não menos importante, check se nesse repositório existe este jar, se não existir, você precisar indicar ao Maven em qual reopsitório buscar este jar.

Fonte: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Answer (score 0):

O artefato em questão **com.outjected:simple-email:jar:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT** não existe no repositório http://repository.primefaces.org (o qual ele está tentando encontrar), verifiquei também o repositório central do maven e não pude encontra-lo.

Voce deve incluir um novo repositório na sua aplicação (pom.xml) ou nas configurações globais do maven (settings.xml). exemplo:

> pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>novo-repo</id>
        <url>http://urlnovorepo.com/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

> settings.xml

```
  <profile>
     <id>meuprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>novo-repo</id>
         <name>novo repositorio global</name>
         <url>http://urlnovorepo.com/repo</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
```

Você pode notar que na configuração global o repositório foi criado em um novo profile, você pode configura-lo como padrão ou ativar o profile diretamente na linha de comando ao executar sua rotina maven.

> via command line maven

```
mvn -Pmeuprofile ...
```

> via bloco de configuração definindo o profile padrão no settings.xml

```
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>meuprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
```

Caso voce não tenha ou saiba o repositório uma possibilidade é adicionar a dependência manualmente no seu repositório local com a linha de comando (na mesma pasta onde estivar o jar em questão):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=simple-email-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar \
     -DgroupId=com.outjected -DartifactId=simple-email \
     -Dversion=0.1.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

Pelo que vi essa biblioteca é um fork de um outro projeto e você pode provavelmente encontra-lo em:
https://github.com/codylerum/simple-email